# Reading selective column data from a text file into a list in Java

Tags: java, file-io

Can someone help me to read a selective column of data in a text file into a list..

e.g.: if the text file data is as follows

```
-------------
id name age
01 ron   21
02 harry 12
03 tom   23
04 jerry 25
-------------
```

from the above data if I need to gather the column "name" using list in java and print it..

Comment: Is the data on new lines or all on one line?

Comment: i need to have only the data which falls under the category "name"

Answer (score 5):

`java.util.Scanner` could be used to read the file, discarding the unwanted columns.
Either print the wanted column values as the file is processed or `add()` them to a `java.util.ArrayList` and print them once processing is complete.

A small example with limited error checking:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

// Skip column headings.

// Read each line, ensuring correct format.
while (s.hasNext())
{
    s.nextInt();         // read and skip 'id'
    names.add(s.next()); // read and store 'name'
    s.nextInt();         // read and skip 'age'
}

for (String name: names)
{
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Comment: thanks,, short and looks simple,, but how can we use this for a huge crowd of data,, i.e. too many columns,, nd i need 2 or more of them?  also saw codes wth split("\t") used,, wat is its purpose here in this kinda codeing?

Comment: Amend the `while` loop depending on the number of columns. Each iteration of the `while` loop represents the processing of a single line. The `split()` would be used on `String` instances when a whole line is read from the file, which is unrequired here as the `Scanner` does the splitting.

Answer (score 3):

Use a file reader and read it line by line, break on the spaces and add any column you want to the List. Use a BufferedReader to grab the lines by something like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\readFile.txt"));
```

Then you can do to grab a line:

```
String line = br.readLine();
```

Finally you can split the string into an array by column by doing this:

```
String[] columns = line.split(" ");
```

Then you can access the columns and add them into the list depending on if you want column 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: Thanks,i gave this a try, but i need to have only the data which falls under the category "name", and i dont have any idea on proceeding beyond that

Comment: If you need only what falls under name do `List.add(columns1[1])`, all this needs to be rapped in a while loop. br.readLine() will return null if it has reached the end of the file, so you can do the following: `while((line = br.readLine()) != null)`. That will continue to read every line of the file and then just add the entry in whichever column you wish to your list, like I showed you above.

Answer (score 1):

Are the columns delimited by tabs?

Look at [Java CSV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/), an open source library for reading comma delimited or tab delimited text files.  SHould do most of the job.  I've never used it myself, but I assume you'd be able to ask for all the values from column 1 (or similar).

Alternatively, you could read the file one line at a time using a `BufferedReader` (which has a `readLine()`) method) and then call `String.split()` and grab the parts you want.