# Java- extract specific data from note pad

Tags: java, text-files, multiple-columns

I have a question on this thread, the answer provided by Majid Laissi

[extract data column-wise from text file using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029721/extract-data-column-wise-from-text-file-using-java/57319784#57319784)

The user wanted to  perform operations **on individual data** according to columns. With that solution how is it working?

This is how I think the solution looked like

```
public class TextTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\MyTemp\\Rank.txt"));

        String line = br.readLine();


        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] columns = line.split("\t");
            System.out.println( columns[0] );
            //System.out.println("my second column : "+ columns[1] );
            //System.out.println("my third column : "+ columns[2] );

        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
065    12000   1
023    15000   2
035    25000   3
076    40000   4
```

Question how was he going to get individual data. Let's say he wanted to just grab 25000, not the matching row. This is not a 2D array so that he can use columns[1][1].

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a 2D array String: And store those values into that matrix. A very naive solution:

```
String matrix[][] = new String[100][1];
int i=0;
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] columns = line.split("\t");
            matrix[i++]= columns;
            System.out.println( columns[0] );
            //System.out.println("my second column : "+ columns[1] );
            //System.out.println("my third column : "+ columns[2] );

}
System.out.println( matrix[2][2]);
```

**Note:** This is not a good practice to uses 2D arrays this ways.

Answer (score 0):

You could also include a row counter to access it via rows and columns:

```
int row = 0;

while((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] columns = line.split(" ");
      System.out.println("my first column : "+ columns[0] );
      System.out.println("my second column : "+ columns[1] );

      if (row == 2) { //denotes 25000
         System.out.println("row item data: " + columns[1]);
      }

      System.out.println("my third column : "+ columns[2] );
      row++;
   }
```