# Using scanner to get integers from a file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java-io

For my java class in college, I need to read a text file that holds the scores of a golf game and add them together to reach a total. I can scan the first column of the file fine, but I cannot figure out how to read the integers in the second, third, etc. column(s).

Here is the pertinent Method:

```
public static int Total(int passed, String fileName) throws IOException   {

    int total = 0;
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    for (int line = 1; line <= 18; line++)   {
        for(int col = passed; col == passed; col++)   {
            total += fileScan.nextInt();
        }
    }

    return total;
}   //End of Total Method
```

Comment: Refer to :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084040/reading-selective-column-data-from-a-text-file-into-a-list-in-java

Comment: Thanks to Nani2015's comment, I learned that this was answered [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084040/reading-selective-column-data-from-a-text-file-into-a-list-in-java